# react axios 401 unauthorized and sometimes 403

Tags: laravel, react-native, networking, axios

I'm building a react native app post requesting laravel php api. it works on postman but not on Axios. Do you know how can i solve? I can't post a form data

I tried other forms sending post request of Axios. but none of them is solution

```
axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'URL',
            params: {
                "api_token": token,
                "name": "talha"
            },
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(response => alert(response)).catch(err => console.warn(err))


-----
const serverURL = "URL";

const http = axios.create({
    timeout: 1000,
    baseURL: serverURL,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp"
});

data is a formdata

await http.post("/passengers", data, config)
            .then(Response => alert(Response.data))
            .catch(error => console.warn("hata", error))
-----
axios.post( 'URL',
                    data,
                    {
                      headers: {
                          Accept: 'application/json',
                          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                      }
                    }
                  ).then(function(){
                    alert('SUCCESS!!');
                  })
                  .catch(function(){
                    alert('FAILURE!!');
                  });
```

postman script:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/vS54dytpCQ/

Comment: Can you post postman script?

Comment: nope. i get the same error 401

Comment: Get it working in postman and provide the details

Comment: send some params and header to api. i already add them to code. but i gives 401 error

Comment: Please generate postman script that works and  publish here

Comment: sorry for delay. i added script now

Comment: You can generate javascript in pistman, that what I look for. In postman is working?

Comment: you can look now

Comment: Export code snippet from Postman if your post is successful in Postman: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/

Comment: now i get error 500 both device and postman maybe the solution is looking mistakes in server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my API helper function for batter development.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const api = async (url, method, body) => {
  /**
   * config object for fetch
   */
  const config = {
    method: 'get',
    baseURL: 'BASEURL WILL BE HERE',
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      authorization: await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token'),
    },
  };

  if (method) {
    config.method = method;
  }
  if (body) {
    config.data = body;
  }

  let response;
  try {
    response = await axios(config);
    return {...response.data};
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e.message);
  }
};

export default api;
```

Then use this function

```
import api from 'filpath';

const functionName = async () => {
  try{
   const res = await api('/passengers', 'POST' posData);
   console.log(res.data);
  } catch(e){
     alert('FAILURE!!')
  }
}
```

**Note**: Save the auth token to AsyncStorage when user login.

Comment: i tried but same. and i send api with params not with header

Comment: await api(`/passengers?param1=${param1}`) you can use this way